# flutter packages get fails

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

When I am trying to add `firebase_auth`, and run `flutter packages get` I get me the following error

```
Running "flutter packages get" in demo...
demo firebase_auth has no versions that match >=0.2.3 <0.3.0 derived from:
- demo depends on version ^0.2.3
```

I am not exactly sure what should I do to fix that.

```
name: full3
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
      path: C:\flutter\packages\flutter
  google_sign_in: "^0.3.1"
  firebase_auth: "^0.2.3"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
        - family: Encode Sans
          fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/EncodeSansExpanded-Light.ttf

  assets:
  - assets/img/facebook.png
  - assets/img/google.png
  - assets/img/logo.png
  - assets/img/signup.png

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section here, in
  # this "flutter" section, as in:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # To add assets from package dependencies, first ensure the asset
  # is in the lib/ directory of the dependency. Then,
  # refer to the asset with a path prefixed with
  # `packages/PACKAGE_NAME/`. Note: the `lib/` is implied, do not
  # include `lib/` in the asset path.
  #
  # Here is an example:
  #
  # assets:
  #  - packages/PACKAGE_NAME/path/to/asset

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
```

Comment: It's a known issue that the error message returned by `pub get` or `flutter packages get` isn't very helpful. There are plans to improve but it requires a broader attempt and will take some time. It just means that some of your dependency constraint prevent finding a set of dependency versions that are all compatible with each other. you can try to enable verbose output to get mote insight, or remove most dependencies until `flutter packages get` succeeds and then add them back one-by-one until it fails, to see which one causes the conflict. You can also try http://mediator.thosakwe.com

Comment: I don't know if it supports Flutter, but otherwise it's often quite helpful for such cases.

Comment: I have tried this on new fresh new projects as well and no hope

Comment: please post your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I have updated the post, please check it when you can.

Comment: What is this line for `path: C:\flutter\packages\flutter`? Did you run `flutter upgrade`?

Comment: `flutter upgrade` works fine, the reason I added the `sdk` by path is that it used to say `Flutter SDK not available` , and adding it by path seemed to fix this problem for me.

Comment: There is some environment variable missing (don't know by heart and only on my phone). These twi dependencies are known to eork together, therefore I suspected SDK version conflicts. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works fine for me.
I just changed the `flutter` dependency.
If this doesn't work for you, there is probably an issue with your Flutter setup.

```
name: full3
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: "^0.3.1"
  firebase_auth: "^0.2.3"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
        - family: Encode Sans
          fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/EncodeSansExpanded-Light.ttf

  assets:
  - assets/img/facebook.png
  - assets/img/google.png
  - assets/img/logo.png
  - assets/img/signup.png

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: I don't think there is a special procedure to reinstall. You can delete the directory that contains it and install it again https://flutter.io/setup/